# Check to see if key,value pair in myArray is in the JSON and if not, add it in

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, compare, key-value

I am trying to check to see if a key,value pair in my array is found in the response JSON and if it is not, then I want to add it to the JSON.

```
$scope.myArray = [{
  "Product_type": "T"
}, {
  "Product_type": "4NB"
}, {
  "Product_type": "C"
}, {
  "Product_type": "39087NB"
}, {
  "Product_type": "16364NB"
}];
```

JSON response array:

```
$scope.data.obj.Product = [{
  "Count": 28,
  "Product_type": "T"
}, {
  "Count": 88,
  "Product_type": "4NB"
}, {
  "Count": 20,
  "Product_type": "C"
}, {
  "Count": 3,
  "Product_type": "39087NB"
}]
```

In this case, the missing key,value pair would be "Product_type": "16364NB". How would I do the check and then add to the response JSON?

Should I iterate through the JSON and then somehow reference myArray to figure out which one is missing, then push it to the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.myArray.forEach(function (a, i) {      
    if ($scope.data.obj.Product.find(function(item) { return item.Product_type === a.Product_type }) === undefined) {
        $scope.data.obj.Product.push(a);       
    }
});
```